# PersistentDataAccessException in worklignt 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We've been seeing exceptions in the worklight logs (messages.log) regarding

> SEVERE: Persistency data access problem periodically.

Full log: http://pastebin.com/CAqn0CnQ

It appears at random and the worklight server hangs for about 5 minutes, after which it recovers and everything works fine.

During the "hang time" the client applications are unable to connect to the server, but after the self-recovery, everyone are good to go. Is there a fix for this?

**Edit**
We had a firewall in between whose timeout was set to 30 minutes.
Now that we have removed the timeout, we see new exceptions regarding `ManagedConnection.destroy()`. We are using JNDI to lookup.

Full log: http://pastebin.com/cA9Eu7Vk

Comment: What is the build number of your Worklight installation? (server and studio). In other words, if you can recreate this in a test environment - download the latest 6.1.0.2 iFix from IBM Fix Central and see if your issue becomes resolved or not.

Comment: BTW, the error seems to be caused from a timeout ("Connection timed out"), so I would double-check the connection to the database for potential bottlenecks.

Comment: Yes, we had a firewall between the server and our DB, but now that we have disabled it, we get a managed connection destroy exception.  I have check the IBM docs and the suggest something related to jndi handling: [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1205_ramachandra/1205_ramachandra.html)

Comment: Actually I still think it's related to the connection... look at the exception: An exception was received by the Data Store Adapter. See original exception message: Closed Connection. with SQL State : 08003 SQL Code : 17008

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an Oracle issue in your network and/or database connection.

> J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal connection error
>   from the Resource Adapter for resource
>   meawallet-server/jdbc/WorklightDS. The exception is:
>   java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection timed
>   out:java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
>
> [26/9/14 5:38:27:703 BST] 00000038
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl          W
>   DSRA0180W: Exception detected during ManagedConnection.destroy().  The
>   exception is:  com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException: DSRA0080E: An
>   exception was received by the Data Store Adapter. See original
>   exception message: Closed Connection. with SQL State : 08003 SQL Code
>   : 17008

Possible solutions:

- https://community.oracle.com/thread/2263117?tstart=0
- Also consider opening an IBM PMR and mention your Oracle setup.